# Timer em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que, a pessoa só possa Votar em um projeto clicando em um botão a cada 24 horas, meio que um Timer em JS.

**Exemplo**: "A pessoa vai votar, e, somente após um dia ela poderá votar novamente".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma implementação que pode fazer é a seguinte, criar um variável para ser incrementada a cada **1 segundo** com o método [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) a partir do clique no botão e quando a variável chegar no valor **86400** que equivale ao total de segundos em 24 horas, você utiliza o [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) para parar o contador, não sei se é a melhor solução para o sua questão, mas, funciona:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('init');
let val = document.getElementById('value');
let count = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.disabled = true;
  counter = setInterval(() => {
    Count()
  },1000)
})

function Count() {
  count++;
  console.log(count)
  if(count == 5) {
    btn.disabled = false;
    clearInterval(counter);
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="init">Contar</button>
```